# Emmet missing semicolon inside css media query in Sublime Text 4

Tags: emmet, sublimetext4, automatic-semicolon-insertion

Emmet autocomplete doesn't add semicolon after css rules inside media query.

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  div {
    display: none
  }
}
```

[Outside media query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef6ad.jpg)
[Inside media query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Oqma.jpg)

Comment: This would probably be best suited as a [bug report on Github](https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin/issues). Search there to make sure it hasn't already been reported.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the plug-in which is under investigation. Keep track of it here: https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin/issues/173

**UPDATE:** This has now been fixed.